# Rails 3: conditional sum before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, function

I've spent quite sometime searching SO, but I'm stuck...

I'd like to calculate the `base_price` for `product` before `product` is saved in the database, but I'd like to make the sum conditional on the `required` field in the variant table.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :variants

  before_save :calculate_price

  private

  def :calculate_price
    self.base_price = variants.where( :required => true ).to_a.sum( &:price_fixed )
  end
end
```

`:required` is a boolean field in `variants`

The statement works for an already saved product, but not one that hasn't been created yet.  Therefore, when I create the product, the price is $0, on update, `base_price` is calculated correctly.

Could someone please help?

Comment: Where/when are Variants assigned to a new Product?

Comment: Variants are assigned to Product in the Product controller.  Now, before_save, I'd like to update the product's base_price.  The problem seems to be related to .where(:required => true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that when you do `[self.]variants.where(...)` in `Product` you're implicitly doing a query like `SELECT * FROM variants WHERE id = #{product.id} AND ...`, but since the product hasn't been saved it has no `id` yet.

However, if you assigned Variants to the new Product in the controller (and thereby it has items in its `self.variants` collection), and those Variants have their `:required` attributes set correctly, you can just filter it using `Enumerable#select` like you would any other array, e.g.:

```
def :calculate_price
  self.base_price = variants.to_a.select( &:required ).sum &:price_fixed
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I always mix myself with the different types of callbacks. Usually, when I want to compute an attribute from other attributes, I go with `before_validation`. `before_save` seems more adapted, but I never got it to work the way I wanted.